# Swift 4 NSObject class, StreamDelegate Not being called

Tags: swift3, swift4, nsobject

Hey guys so I'm having a problem in my NSObject class file when setting delegates.

```
class NetWorkController: NSObject, StreamDelegate{)
```

when I try to set

```
inputStream!.delegate =  self
```

However if I do the same in my UIViewcontroller class it does work

```
class ConnectPlayerViewController: UIViewController, StreamDelegate {}
```

I don't understand why it works here but not in my NSObject class, thanks for the help in advance.

Heres the StreamDelegate handler function:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if aStream == self.inputStream {
            self.inputStreamHandle(eventCode)
        }
        else if aStream == self.outputStream {
            self.outputStreamHandle(eventCode)
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Theres no error, the function for StreamDelegate just never runs. I tried remaking the class file and it does the same thing. Ill add the function that I want to run when setting the inputStream.delegate to the question

Comment: Are you creating an instance of `NetWorkController` anywhere?

Comment: No where I would I create that?

Comment: In a view controller. Maybe `ConnectPlayerViewController`?

Comment: Ahh I misunderstand your question yes I am creating an instance and calling it as so : NetWorkController().connect()

Comment: So its being called and run but the delegate function associated with my stream variable isn't.

Comment: You need to keep the instance in a property of the view controller, or else it will disappear since nothing is referencing it.

Comment: Thank you! Yes so I just created a  variable: var networkhandler = NetWorkController() and then called it using networkhandler.connect()   thanks a lot for the help! Ill update post with the solution

Comment: You should not update your post with the solution. I have already posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have

```
NetWorkController().connect()
```

in some method of your VC. This does not work because of [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Your object will "disappear" after the method returns.

You need to declare it as a property:

```
// outside of any method, at class level
let controller = NetWorkController()

// in some method
controller.connect()
```

Now the delegate method should get called.

Comment: I have the same scenario in Objective-C. Could you please help me with it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993370/ios-delegate-method-not-called-in-nsobject-class

Comment: @KuldeepBhimte Sorry, but I'm not familiar with Objective-C syntax.